# Biopython: adding section in middle sequence an having features aligned

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I want to add section of sequence in middle of previous sequence(in gb file) and have all features still indexed by old sequence.

For example:

previous sequence: ATAGCCATTGAATGTGTGTG**TGTCCTA**GAGGGCCTAAAA

fetaure: misc_feature    complement(20..27)
                     /gene="Py_ori+A"

I add `TTTTTT` in position 10.

new sequence: ATAGCCATTG**TTTTTT**AAGTGTGTG**TGTCCTA**GAGGGCCTAAAA

fetaure: misc_feature    complement(**26**..**33**)
                     /gene="Py_ori+A"

Indexes of features changed because feature must still be about segment TGTCCTA. I want to save the new sequence in a new gb file.

Is there any biopython function or method that could add segment of sequence in middle of old sequence and add length of added segment to indexes of features, that are after the added segment?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Call `+` on your sliced segments (e.g. `a + b`). As long as you didn't slice into a feature you should be OK.

---

The long version:

the BioPython supports feature joining. It is done simply by calling `a + b` on the respective `SeqRecord` classes (the features are part of the `SeqRecord` object not the `Seq` class.).

There are a quirk to be aware of regarding slicing sequence with features. If you happen to do slicing in the feature, the feature will not be present in resulting `SeqRecord`.

I've tried to illustrate the behaviour in the following code.

```py
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.SeqFeature import SeqFeature, FeatureLocation


# THIS IS OK

a = SeqRecord(
    Seq('ACGTA'),
    id='a',
    features=[
        SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(2,4,1), id='f1')
    ]
)

b = SeqRecord(
    Seq('ACGTA'),
    id='b',
    features=[
        SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(2,4,1), id='f2')
    ]
)

c = a + b

print('seq a')
print(a.seq)
print(a.features)

print('\nseq b')
print(b.seq)
print(b.features)

print("\n two distinct features joined in seq c")
print(c.seq)
print(c.features)
print("notice how the second feature has now indices (7,9), instead of 2,4\n")


# BEWARE
# slicing into the feature will remove the feature !

print("\nsliced feature removed")
d = a[:3]
print(d.seq)
print(d.features)
# Seq('ACG')
# []

# However slicing around the feature will preserve it
print("\nslicing out of the feature will preserve it")
e = c[1:6]
print(e.seq)
print(e.features)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
seq a
ACGTA
[SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(2), ExactPosition(4), strand=1), id='f1')]

seq b
ACGTA
[SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(2), ExactPosition(4), strand=1), id='f2')]

 two distinct features joined in seq c
ACGTAACGTA
[SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(2), ExactPosition(4), strand=1), id='f1'), SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(7), ExactPosition(9), strand=1), id='f2')]
notice how the second feature has now indices (7,9), instead of 2,4


sliced feature removed
ACG
[]

slicing out of the feature will preserve it
CGTAA
[SeqFeature(FeatureLocation(ExactPosition(1), ExactPosition(3), strand=1), id='f1')]
```